# SQL | Convert varchar to date and get a range of records

Tags: sql, date

My date format in Database is in varchar, and I need to get a range of order data from 1st April 2022 to 3rd March 2023. The column name is called **date**

The date records are written like this: "28-12-2022"

I understand to get a range of date, I need to convert varchar to date format.
I searched through google and found many SQL syntax suggestions, but I could not get it to work.

Please assist

```
SELECT fname, emailid, highrisk, count(*),sum(amount) 
FROM member 
JOIN orders ON member.sno =orders.customerid 
WHERE highrisk LIKE 'Yes' AND convert(datetime, date, 105) between '01-04-2022' and '31-03-2023'
GROUP BY fname, emailid, highrisk;
```

## **Update with Solution**

So after much testing, we managed to come up with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT fname, emailid, highrisk, count(*),sum(amount) 
FROM member JOIN orders ON member.sno =orders.customerid 
WHERE highrisk LIKE 'Yes' 
AND orders.status='completed' 
AND str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y') >= ' 2022-04-01' 
AND str_to_date(date,'%d-%m-%Y') <= ' 2023-04-30' 
GROUP BY fname, emailid, highrisk;
```

Comment: From your syntax, it looks like SQL server but could you tag the RDBMS you are using really.

Comment: BTW I would strongly suggest to use date\datetime type for a date\datetime.

Comment: Note that `'01-04-2023' < '31-03-2022'`, if you're using varchar. I'd say using varchar for dates means `highrisk = 'Yes'`!

Comment: To answer some comments, I am not the original SQL admin, so "date" was already varchar, I don't know what it will affect if I change the datatype. We are using phpmyadmin. What we are doing in the SQl is to filter all members who are considered "High Risk", count how many orders they made and sum their orders from 1st April 2022 to 3rd March 2023. The date is where I am having issue since it is not in datetime format

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @user2741620 You can answer your question by your self and after 24 hours later mark it as accepted answer. So don't post the answer into the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fname, emailid, highrisk, count(*),sum(amount) 
FROM member 
INNER JOIN orders ON member.sno = orders.customerid 
WHERE highrisk = 'Yes' AND 
  convert(datetime, date, 105) between '20220401' and '20230331'
GROUP BY fname, emailid, highrisk;
```

Notes: Do not use sum() with joined tables, unless you are sure this is a 1-to-many relation (probably it is in your case).

EDIT: MySQL:

```
SELECT fname, emailid, highrisk, count(*),sum(amount) 
FROM member 
INNER JOIN orders ON member.sno = orders.customerid 
WHERE highrisk = 'Yes' AND 
  STR_TO_DATE(date,'%d-%m-%Y') between '2022-04-01' and '2023-03-31'
GROUP BY fname, emailid, highrisk;
```

Comment: I tried but it gave the error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', 105) between '20220401' and '20230331'
GROUP BY fname, emailid, highrisk LIMI' at line 5"

Comment: @user2741620, I already asked you to tag the database you are using. That syntax is for SQL server and it works perfectly well. If you have mySQL, then you should specify it and you would get something different. Editing my answer to add a solution for MySQL.